# Upload executable file to PyPI by operating system?

Tags: python, binary, package, installation, pypi

Is there a way that I can upload complied binary files as a package in PyPI? And how do I detect different operating system?

I've noticed that PyPI some package is doing like this way, such as Pyinstaller, but not sure on how to achieve it.

Thanks!